# how to print no. from n to 1 from the pattern in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

display the loop

```
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
  5 4 3 2 1
    3 2 1
      1
```

how to print this pattern no idea of printing it from n to 1

```
read -p "Enter rows:" rows

for ((a=$rows;a>=1;a--))
do
for ((b=$rows;b>$a;b--))
do
    echo -n " "
done
for ((c=1;c<=$a;c++))
do
    echo -n '* '
    if [ $c = $a ]
    then
        echo -e '\n'
    fi
done
done
```

please help to print this pattern loop not have enough spaces if i take n as 7 then printing it in 4 line will be difficult for me

Comment: I don't see how your code could possibly related to the problem you are going to solve.  For a start: I would loop over the number of entries to print in each line: So the loop variable would start with 7, and go down in steps of **2** (7->5->3->1). This gives you the number of entries for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate error is that your requirement calls for subtracting two items from the start in each iteration, but you only subtract one.

More generally, probably avoid `echo -e` entirely; learn to use `printf` if you need detailed control over newlines etc.

```
for ((a=$rows; a>=1; a-=2)); do
  printf -v sep "%$((rows - a))s" ""
  for ((b=$a; b>=1; b--)); do
    printf "%s%i" "$sep" "$b"
    sep=" "
  done
  printf '\n'
done
```

And, as demonstrated here, probably learn to indent your code to show how blocks are nested.

Tangentially, perhaps better to accept the number of rows as a command-line argument rather than prompt interactively for a value. Interactive I/O is pesky when you want to use your script as part of another larger script.